# How can I properly use the javascript function JSON.parse()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array that is printed in JSON

```
[{"Name":"John Ranniel","Age":"19","City":"Manila"},{"Contact":"09197875656","Relation":"Sister"}]
```

For some reason, I divided the JSON into two parts.

In javascript I used `JSON.parse()` to decode the JSON above.

for example:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(response); //The response variable contains the above JSON

alert(arr[0].Name) //Still it outputs John Ranniel, but If i change the content of the alert box on the second part of the JSON,
alert(arr[1].Contact) // It has no output, I don't know if there is a problem with the index of the array.
```

Comment: PS: there is no `Contact` attribute there.

Comment: Also, perhaps you meant `arr[1]["Emergency Contact"]`?

Comment: Typo error, it's just an example. It's different with the code that I'm writing. But they have the same problem.

Comment: [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) expects text as a first parameter, not an array

Comment: It's a text, it comes from an echo of a PHP.

Comment: *It has no output,* Meaning, the alert box does not appear? It appears, but is blank? It appears, but with some error? Also, it's confusing to say "printed in JSON". Do you mean to say it's a JSON string? Finally, it's also confusing to say "divided the JSON into two parts". You probably mean "structure the JSON into a two-element array".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JSON is a string type:

```
'[{"Name":"John Ranniel","Age":"19","City":"Manila"},{"Emergency Contact":"09197875656","Relation":"Sister"}]'
```

and then, you can use,

```
var arr = JSON.parse(response); //The response variable contains the above JSON

console.log(arr[0].Name);
console.log(arr[1]['Emergency Contact']); // There is no 'Contact' property iun your object, and you should use this when there's a space in the name of the property.
```

See:

```js
var response = '[{"Name":"John Ranniel","Age":"19","City":"Manila"},{"Emergency Contact":"09197875656","Relation":"Sister"}]';

var arr = JSON.parse(response);

console.log(arr[0].Name);
console.log(arr[1]['Emergency Contact']); // There is no 'Contact' property iun your object, and you should use this when there's a space in the name of the property.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse something which is already a JavaScript object, and does not need to be parsed. You need to parse JSON strings. This is not a JSON string. It's a JavaScript object.

Consider the following:

```
JSON.parse([1,2])
```

This will coerce the array `[1,2]` into the string "1,2". JSON.parse will then choke on the `,`, since it doesn't belong there in a valid JSON string.

In your case the object will be coerced to the string

```
"[object Object],[object Object]"
```

JSON.parse will accept the leading `[` as the beginning of the array, then throw on the following character, the `o`, since it does not belong there in a proper JSON string.

But you say that the JSON.parse worked and resulted in `arr`. In other words, the parameter you fed to JSON.parse apparently **was** a string, and was parsed correctly. In that case, the alerts will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON structure is array, must be parse to JSON,use **JSON.stringify** parse this to JSON:

```
var json = [{"Name":"John Ranniel","Age":"19","City":"Manila"},{"Contact":"09197875656","Relation":"Sister"}];

var str = JSON.stringify(json);

console.log(json);

var arr = JSON.parse(str);
alert(arr[0].Name) //Still it outputs John Ranniel, but If i change the content of the alert box on the second part of the JSON,
alert(arr[1].Contact) // It has no output, I don't know if there is a problem with the index of the array.
```

Demo: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/3rwad5s6/)

This JSON is array, you can use directly:

```
var json = [{"Name":"John Ranniel","Age":"19","City":"Manila"},{"Contact":"09197875656","Relation":"Sister"}];
alert(json[0].Name);
alert(json[1].Contact);
```

Comment: Why would I stringify it, then immediately parse it? Just work with the original object.